# How can I rotate the arrow marker in a Bokeh plot to show wind speed direction?

Tags: python, bokeh, scatter-plot, marker

What I am trying to do is to use a scatter plot to display wind speed and its direction.  I wanted to use the triangle marker and use the rotation to indicate wind speed.  However, since bokeh default triangle is an equilateral triangle, the wind direction actually gets confusing (you can't tell which is the head which is the tail).

Is there any way I can change/create my own triangle that is Isosceles instead? this is so that I can tell which is head which is tail in the triangle.

here is a sample of what I have:
[Bokeh Scatter Plot with Rectangular Marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW3oQ.png)

Just to be clear here is a quick sketch of what shape marker I am looking for:
[Desired Rectangle vs Default Rectangle Marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lXC5.png)

Here is a sample dataset.  I have also used the arrow as suggested by J'e. Here is a sample result:

[image: Sample Dataset]
[image: Sample Result]

This works ok but is not perfect.  Because I plan to embed this plot and stretch it (sizing_mode="stretch_both"), the angles will look off.  I don't think this was a problem when using rectangles and angles to draw.

Comment: To clarify, you want a plot with a number of triangles that each "rotates" to indicate the wind direction for the given lon/lat?  It may be helpful to add an image to your post.

Comment: Yes, I can easily create a plot with markers and rotate each one based on wind direction.  However, with a triangle of equal length sides, it become difficult to distinguish which way the triangle was actually rotated (see pictures added to comments)

Comment: If you like the look but are concerned with the stretch changing the angle, perhaps thinking about the problem in terms of limits would help make your Delta X, Delta Y values very very small.  There is no realistic amount of resizing that would change the angle. - If you're happy with the VeeHead, don't forget to accept the answer. You will also get reputation points for doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything in the API that will do this directly.  Using `bokeh.models VeeHead`, you can draw a VeeHead arrow

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import Arrow, VeeHead

# Create a sin wave of x/y coordinates 
N = 300
x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
y = np.sin(x)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))
TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"

# create a new plot and add a renderer
p = figure(tools=TOOLS, width=700, height=700, title=None)
p.line('x', 'y', source=source)


for i in range(N-1):
    p.add_layout(Arrow(end=VeeHead(size=25,fill_alpha=0.5), x_start=x[i], y_start=y[i], x_end=x[i+1], y_end=y[i+1])) 
show(p)
```

[image: VeeHead no Tail]

Rather than having virtually no tail like in the first example, you you add one like in this example.  Note that the tail has it's own style which I didn't set in this example.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import Arrow, VeeHead

# prepare some date
N = 300
x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
y = np.sin(x)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))
TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"

# create a new plot and add a renderer
p = figure(tools=TOOLS, width=700, height=700, title=None)
p.line('x', 'y', source=source)

for i in range(11, N-1):
    m = (y[i]-y[i-1])/(x[i]-x[i-1])
    Y = m*(x[i]-x[i-10]) # not point slope
    p.add_layout(Arrow(end=VeeHead(size=25,fill_alpha=0.5), x_start=x[i-10], y_start=Y, x_end=x[i], y_end=y[i])) 
show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: The only issue with arrows are that they take two points in order to be drawn (not an angle).  it's is easily done if  both the x and y axis are of the same unit and same size.  It get's more complicated when x is time based and y is mph.  Now if there was a way I could get the "length" of x axis and "length of y axis to figure out proportions, then i could used this.

Comment: can you add a couple rows of you data to your original question?  I think this can still be done